# Randomly generate object from array and use useState?

Tags: reactjs

I want to randomly generate 4 objects from my array on page load.  However, eslint keeps showing a warning. If i fix the eslint warning, my app goes into a forever loop (since the depencency required to fix the warning will make useEffect run forever).  How can i fix this? Or is my only option to ignore the warning?

```
function QuestionPopulator({
  data: { questionCollection, category}
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const filteredQuestionByCategory = category && {
    items: questions
      .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
      .filter((item) => !router.asPath.includes(item.slug))
      .slice(0, 4)
  };

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (questionCollection?.items?.length > 0) {
      setQuestions(questionCollection);
    } else {
      setQuestions(filteredQuestionsByCategory);
    }
  }, [questionCollection, filteredQuestionByCategory]); // i orgiinally coded just an empty array [], but eslint requires these two

  return (//returns the randomly sorted and filtered array) 
}
```

Comment: `filteredQuestionByCategory` is created each time when page re-renders, thus triggering the effect repeatedly. Also, is your component a React component? If all you're trying to return is an array, it doesn't make sense to make it one.

Comment: @technophyle It is a react component. I've heard that twice now (don't useState), but then what am i doing wrong? I can't directly set questions =  questionCollection?.items?.length > 0 ? questionCollection : filteredQuestionsByCategory . Because it gives the warning: : warning: text content did not match. server

Comment: @Omilight what happens when you move the `filteredQuestionByCategory` definiton inside the `useEffect`'s Effect function? Does the issue persist with `questionCollection`?